# Static Method/Function of Class in PHP

Tags: php, class, function, methods, static

I trying to use static method (I do not want to instantiate a class).
and I put this example.

```
<?php
  class RootClass {
    const Member = 20;
    public static function Member() {
      return self::Member;
    }
  }

  class NewClass {
    private $ValNewClass = "";
    private function InitNewClass() {
      $this->ValNewClass = RootClass::Member();
    }
    public static function GetNewVal() {
      $this->InitNewClass();
      $Validation = true;
      if ($this->ValNewClass>10){
        echo "greater than 10";
        $Validation = false;
      } else {
        echo "Not greater than 10";
      }
      return $Validation;
    }
  }
  $Val2 = NewClass::GetNewVal();  //It must print "greater than 10"
?>
```

**I need to know where is my mistakes.**
This is not real code, only is simple form for ask.

Thank you.

Comment: Why `$this` here: `$this->InitNewClass();`?

Comment: As a side note, use proper naming convention, ALL_CAPS for constants, lower_case() or camelCase() for function names and $variables, and First_letter_uppercased for class names.

Comment: You can not use `$this` is static methods, change it to `self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  class Rootclass {
    const MEMBER = 20;
    public static function member() {
      return self::MEMBER;
    }
  }

  class Newclass {
    private static $valnewclass = "";
    private function initnewclass() {
      self::$valnewclass = Rootclass::member();
    }
    public static function getnewval() {
      self::initnewclass(); //Initialice Val for make comparation
      $validation = true;
      if (self::$valnewclass>10){
        echo "<br>greater than 10";
        $Validation = false;
      } else {
        echo "<br>Not greater than 10";
      }
      return $validation;
    }
  }
  $Val2 = Newclass::getnewval();  //It must print "greater than 10"
  echo "<br>After";
?>
```

**Thank you**
The code is working.

Chepe.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP the $this variable is not available inside a method declared as static.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to non-static fields, inside your static method. Values inside this kind of classess cannot be object-dependent. When you use $this->field, you're refering to the value inside an instance of the class. If you want to modify static field, you should use self::field.